# Plant with purple blooms that close each night

Tags: identification, flowers

The depicted plant closes its blooms at night. It has purple, thin, spidery petals, as well as thick, soft, needle-shaped leafs. I obtained it at a handout 2-3 years ago at a botanical garden here in Central Europe and have planted it outside. It has paid me faithful company ever since.

What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is the hardy ice plant, or *Delosperma cooperi*. It is not originally from Europe, but from South Africa. See [here](https://blog.mountain-plover.com/2013/05/16/hardy-ice-plant/) for confirmation. It is a succulent, with halucinogenic compounds (DMT) in the leaves, so be careful not to eat it (unless you're in for a trip).

Comment: Excellent & yes, definitely a [*Delosperma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delosperma) and most likely a [*Delosperma cooperi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delosperma_cooperi). And I heed advise from the Netherlands re trips :-)

Comment: I wouldn't advice to use DMT, I have read stories about it. They say you get in another dimension with dancing mechanical elves...

Comment: This was just meant as an innocent joke. Sorry if it caused a misunderstanding. I'm not interested in such trips at all. Again, thanks for your kind response.

Comment: No worries, and your welcome! In my youth I was interested in these psychoactive compounds, but DMT always seemed a bit too much. So I thought I warn you in case you were really serious ;-)

Comment: Right & BTW, here's another instance where [gardening](https://www.amazon.com/Second-Nature-Gardeners-Michael-Pollan/dp/0802140114) and [trips](https://www.amazon.com/Change-Your-Mind-Consciousness-Transcendence/dp/1594204225/) apparently have come to overlap in perhaps interesting ways.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of hallucinogens from nature. In my youth (mid 90s), we had a book "[Uit je Bol](http://uitjebol.net/)" in Dutch (never translated to English unfortunately), in which all psychoactive drugs were explained including a lot of natural drugs as well, like mushrooms and peyote, etc.